# Why might VSCode think devcontainer configuration files were changed every time I open the devcontainer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm using VSCode with the devcontainers feature. I recently made a large update to my devcontainer configuration, moving the devcontainer from a single DockerFile to `docker-compose.yaml`. Everything's working fine except that and I'm finding every time I start up the devcontainer, VSCode shows a toast notification in the bottom right corner informing me that the devcontainer *"Configuration file(s) changed...The container might need to be rebuilt to apply the changes."*

If I select the provided option to rebuild the container, I'm still presented with this same message the next time I open VSCode and start up the devcontainer. **Basically, VSCode thinks the configuration files for the devcontainer were changed every time I open the devcontainer, even though they haven't been changed since I last built the container.**

At the moment, this is just a very minor annoyance--the devcontainer works fine and all I need to do is ignore the toast notification once on startup. It appears as though something is going wrong though. Does anyone have any idea as to why VSCode might be showing this message each time I start up the devcontainer? Or better yet, how to address this message in a better way than simply ignoring it?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on my end. It will stop appearing if I hit "Ignore", but hitting "Rebuild" will rebuild the container and VSCode will still display the notification after rebuilding the container.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be happening to me because I was trying to append a directory to the PATH variable, referencing the exisisting path variable as mentioned in the [documentation](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#variables-in-devcontainerjson):

`"remoteEnv": {"PATH": "${containerWorkspaceFolder}/bin:${containerEnv:PATH}"},`

Doesn't seem like that is intended behavior, but once I removed it, the constant pop-up went away.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do not know what is the reason for this bug but I managed to achieve the effect so that the message no longer appears.

As your project is using docker-compose just try to stop and remove the container(s) following these steps:

1. find name or id of any container from your project using `docker ps | grep my_project`.
2. find project name of this container using `docker inspect my_project_devcontainer_some_container | grep '"com.docker.compose.project"'`
3. down this project from `.devcontainer` directory using `cd .devcontainer && docker compose --project-name my_project_devcontainer down`
4. reopen project in container